# system.stackoverflowexception Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I am getting a System.StackOverFlowException when the code hits this function.

Where stringtype is user defined tupe and equals int the function in the type library.

```
  public static bool Equals(StringType leftHand, StringType rightHand)
  {
       if (leftHand == rightHand)
       {
          return true;
       }
       if ((leftHand == "0") || (rightHand == "0"))
       {
          return false;
       }
       return (leftHand.myValue.Equals(rightHand.myValue) && leftHand.myState.Equals(rightHand.myState));
   }
```

Comment: It's better if you tell us the overridden operators of your `StringType` class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This

```
if (leftHand == rightHand)
```

change to

```
if (object.ReferenceEquals(leftHand, rightHand))
```

You probably redefined the `==` operator to call `Equals`.

And I hope you don't have an implicit operator that from `string` creates `StringType`, because otherwise

```
if ((leftHand == "0") || (rightHand == "0"))
```

will probably call itself for the same reason.

Probably

```
if ((leftHand.myValue == "0") || (rightHand.myValue == "0"))
```

would be better.

Comment: Thanks xanatos , When I changed the code it ran without error. What you guess is right that we redefined the == operator. I am just curious to know what why it was giving an error when lefthand == right hand.

Comment: because `leftHand == rightHand` called your redefined operator, that in turn called `Equals`, that in turn called your redefined operator and so on. Instead of using `object.ReferenceEquals` you could have done: `((object)leftHand) == ((object)rightHand)` because operators can't be `virtual`, but I think that using the `object.ReferenceEquals` is more clear. Remember if you create `struct`s that you don't need to do this check. Every value of `struct` type is always distinct, for example `MyFunc(structValue, structValue)` in `MyFunc` you have 2x different copies of `structValue`.

Comment: You were making the class recursive with no way out.  `.Equals(StringType, StringType)` would immediately call `==(StringType)` which would then immediately call `.Equals(StringType, StringType)`, et cetera ad absurdum until the call stack ran out of room and threw a StackOverflowException.